# Why is my program giving me an Abort Trap: 6 error?

Tags: c, macos

This code is supposed to sort the array of strings, but around the second iteration of the main loop in selection sort, it gives me an Abortion Trap: 6 error. I am running it on the terminal in a Mac. Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int letSize = 20;
int vecSize;
char **array1;

void selectionSort (int low, int high)
{
    char *temp = malloc ((letSize + 1) * sizeof (char));
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = low; i < high - 1; i++) {
        int indexOfMin = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < high; j++)
            if (strcmp (array1[j], array1[indexOfMin]) < 0)
                indexOfMin = j;
        //after second main loop, error occurs
        strcpy (temp, array1[i]);
        strcpy (array1[i], array1[indexOfMin]);
        strcpy (array1[indexOfMin], temp);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int i, j;

    printf ("Enter size of items to be sorted: ");
    scanf ("%d", &vecSize);
    array1 = malloc (vecSize * sizeof (char *));
    for (i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)
        array1[i] = malloc ((letSize + 1) * sizeof (char));

    srand (time (NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < vecSize; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= letSize; j++) {
            if (j != letSize) {
                char randLet = 'A' + (random () % 26);
                array1[i][j] = randLet;
            } else
                array1[i][j] = '\0';
        }
    }
    selectionSort (0, vecSize);
}
```

This is the code that is giving me trouble. It compiles without any problems and it also takes the input from the user, but after wards it gives me the error of abort trap: 6. What could be causing this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just my (correct) opinion: `selectionSort` shouldn't have to be told how large the vector is.

Comment: Good point. I was using a template code but that code wasn't relying on global variables. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Look over your *sort* routine, it looks like there are multiple problems, beginning with missing braces `'{...}` wrapping the `if (strcmp...` clause. Even with that change, I'm not positive that is a correct selection sort. You will need to confirm.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but your data is an array of pointers; why do you swap the strings instead of swapping just the pointers? I.e. use plain assignments instead of `strcpy`s and get rid of `malloc` in the sorting function.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Come on, the braces is just a code style point, and not a universally accepted one at that. Care to elaborate on the "multiple problems" you saw? Otherwise your comment is kinda unconstructive.

Comment: You know what. After failing to spot a critical issue with my eyes, I've compiled your code and ran it multiple times with vecSize=100000. It didn't crash, and it produced correctly sorted output. Of course it doesn't prove there is no problem, but I suggest you check your environment.

Comment: Turns out there was something wrong with my environment, more precisely strcpy wasn't working correctly. I thank you for your help @atzz, I did the pointer exchange instead of the strcpy because its more practical and a lot easier.

Comment: @atzz, the concern was that the braces were need to keep the tests in a single block, not "*style*". It took a minute, but the block where the braces were needed was the missing check to prevent copying the string over itself.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sorry, you're still making no sense. Which tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you attempt a copy when `j == indexOfMin` (or when `j == i`) which attempts to copy overlapping memory regions with `strcpy` (you can with `memmove`, not `strcpy`). From `man strcpy`

> The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src, including
>   the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed to by dest.
>   `The strings may not overlap`, ....

You simply need a check for and copy only if `j != indexOfMin` to prevent trying to copy a string over itself. e.g.:

```
void selectionSort (int low, int high)
{
    char *temp = malloc ((letSize + 1) * sizeof (char));
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = low; i < high - 1; i++) {
        int indexOfMin = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < high; j++)
            if (strcmp (array1[j], array1[indexOfMin]) < 0)
                if (j != indexOfMin) {
                    indexOfMin = j;
                    strcpy (temp, array1[i]);
                    strcpy (array1[i], array1[indexOfMin]);
                    strcpy (array1[indexOfMin], temp);
                }
    }
    free (temp);
}
```

Also remember to `free (temp)` or you have a guaranteed memory leak.

Comment: While your remark regarding `strcmp` is formally correct, in practice this specific case won't cause any problem in all existing implementations. So the cause of the topickstarter's crash must have been something else.

Comment: It will depend on the implementation. I haven't looked at the `apple` source code, but I suspect it differs from the Linux implementation. It did not cause a crash on my Linux box, but apparently his implementation is trapping the memory error. Run it through `valgrind` and look.

Comment: Argument checks in debug build? Could be, point conceded. Though I'd expect such checks with `assert`-like human-readable output.

Comment: The pointer-swap was the way to go. Eliminated the issue and saved a number of calls to `malloc`, `strcpy`, etc.. For me it was another reminder of how renaming loop variables can make it harder to visually see a problem.